# Using Blender with rollAPP/iPad

Tags: osx

I am considering purchasing an iPad Air for schoolwork (mainly writing essays and stuff) but occasionally, I would like to use Blender. Currently, I plan to use a program called rollAPP (https://www.rollapp.com/app/blender) which utilizes my browser to run Blender.

I have a heavy-duty workstation at home which I use for Blender 90% of the time. I will render on this PC, and I will mainly use the iPad to check my render status/create and shade 3d models.

Does anyone know if this rollAPP technique will work well, or another how to use Blender on an iPad?

Thanks!

-Jake